# How to solve render-blocking JavaScript and css

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried all the step suggested in the all the links found not of them talking about the specifics of the below js and css file. My Question is how can one load these file asynchronously in magento. The google page speed test shows these are blocking the page load. Please don't add this question as duplicate as none of them has answered this.

magestore/bannerslider/jquery-1.7.min.js
magestore/bannerslider/jquery.flexslider.js

magestore/bannerslider/flexslider.css

I really appreciate the expert to look into this. I have seen many such questions unanswered. I am using magento 1.9.2 and the above js is not a part of page.xml file.

Please provide your expertise suggestion. Thanks